# Varying results from predict() method - Keras , Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

this is my first post, feel free to correct me, if I am asking my question ambiguous.

Relevant packages for the code snippets:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
```

I am training my model with Keras Functional API. It is being saved by means of the ModelCheckpoint:

```
ModelCheckpoint('path_save_model', save_best_only=True, monitor='recall', mode='max')
```

In a new script, I imported it simply like this:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('path_save_model')
```

I prepared data for one prediction. The input data is a 3d-numpy array. (Processing issues should be excluded, since I am using the same array over and over again.)
Each time, I get a different prediction, which is confusing me extremely. If I run this piece:

```
np.testing.assert_allclose(model.predict(3d_np_array), model.predict(3d_np_array))
```

I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "C:\Users\me.virtualenvs\my_project\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing_private\utils.py", line 1528, in assert_allclose
> assert_array_compare(compare, actual, desired, err_msg=str(err_msg),
> File "C:\Users\me.virtualenvs\my_project\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing_private\utils.py", line 842, in assert_array_compare
> raise AssertionError(msg)
> AssertionError:
> Not equal to tolerance rtol=1e-07, atol=0
> Mismatched elements: 17406 / 17500 (99.5%)
> Max absolute difference: 0.17088592
> Max relative difference: 3.6502254

It is such a simple procedure, that I have no clue where my bug could sneak in. I don't think the prediction of a trained and imported model should contain any randomness. However, just to be sure, I tried setting all seeds and testing it with code taken from Keras documentation.

```
import random
random.seed(123)
np.random.seed(123)
tf.random.set_seed(1234)
print(hash("keras"))
```

The hash stays each time the same, the predicted results still differ.

I kind of hope, I am just missing something obvious.

Note:

```
np.testing.assert_allclose(model.predict(np.zeros((1,2500,4))),model.predict(np.zeros((1,2500,4))))
```

Led to a similiar output:

> Mismatched elements: 17385 / 17500 (99.3%)

**SOLVED**

see answer

Comment: What is `3d_np_array`, can you safely say that they are exactly the same object? I'd guess that the mistake lies there.

Comment: It is one and the same array. I saved it to be sure there lies no mistake in creating the input. Running np.testing.assert_allclose(3d_np_array, 3d_np_array) does not cause any warning. I tried changing it's dtype from uint16 to float32, but that did not help either.

Comment: Just ran it with np.testing.assert_allclose(model.predict(np.zeros((1,2500,4))),model.predict(np.zeros((1,2500,4)))) -> Mismatched elements: 17385 / 17500 (99.3%)

Comment: hmm, strange. The second thing that I'd check is to assure loaded model and current model is the same. Maybe load_model path is different (but similar) ?

Comment: I got it. I missread the keras documentation about the dropout layer. Or let's be honest, it is weirdly discribed. However, it was just the dropout causing randomness. Something, I of course did not describe in my question... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you, instead of writing down edit, you can answer your question and accept it as a best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the wrong impression from Keras documentation of the dropout layer. Actually, I am still puzzled by it. I set training=True, because of this statement:

> Note that the Dropout layer only applies when training is set to True
> such that no values are dropped during inference.

See [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularization_layers/dropout/)

I am not using the argument "training" at all any more, hoping that the default will be the normal usage of a dropout layer (-> dropout while training and not while testing and predicition). I hope this is correct. In case, I should be setting training to False in order to get the wished behavior, please give me a shout.